# Cross entropy between distribution and its scaled self

Tags: classification, entropy, information-theory, cross-entropy

I am trying to quantitatively explain something I am seeing. I have a data set with a certain statistical distribution $p(x)$. I build a classifier to identify when something in my data set falls into one of several categories. Now say I test this classifier on the training set, but scaled so that its standard deviation $\sigma_q = a\sigma_p$. From what I am seeing, my classifier does a lot worse when $a < 1$ than when $a > 1$. Could someone explain in information theory terms why this would be?

I tried looking at this in terms of cross entropy:

\begin{align*}
H_p(q(x)) &= -\sum_x q(x) \log (p(x)) \\
&\geq H(p(x))
\end{align*}

where $H_p(q(x))$ is the cross entropy between $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, and $H(p(x))$ is the entropy of $p(x)$. Since the cross entropy is always larger than entropy (equal when $p = q$), we would have more uncertainty for any $q(x) \neq p(x)$, but how do I quantify how this changes based on whether $a < 1$ or $a > 1$, i.e. whether $\sigma_q < \sigma_p$ or $\sigma_q > \sigma_p$?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question...your data is drawn from $p$, but what's $q$? Are you training a classifier on data drawn from $p$, then using it to classify separate data drawn from $q$?

Comment: Yes. Basically there is some normalization being done, but there tends to be some variation in the resulting standard deviation. I'm trying to understand why that variation affects us more when the resulting std is smaller than nominal vs. bigger.

Comment: Is scaling the only thing that's happening, or could there also be other changes (e.g. shifts, changes to the shape of the distribution, etc.) that are correlated with scaling?

Comment: Scaling is all that is happening. The issue shows up if we test on the training set after scaling. We go from great results to very poor very fast if std decreases, and much more slowly if it increases.